# Moving to composer from git submodules

Tags: git, composer-php, git-submodules

Do I have/is it good practice to remove git submodules before I run 'composer install'? Or could I just install and bet that composer figuring it out?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for code, not best practices for software installation. Sorry, this is not the right site for your question. Try one of the other [Stack Exchanges](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove them (assuming you are talking about having git submodules in the `vendor` folder).